# Session variables looped in IF

Tags: mysql, session-variables

What would this mean?
I fail to understand the syntax.

```
SELECT if(@s, @s:=@s+1, @s:=1) as rownum, user_id, operation FROM users_list
```

Answer (score 1):

This initializes a variable `@s` with `1` at the first record and adds `1` for every following row. This is a rank mechanism to get the row number for every record in a select dynamically.

The result could look like this

```
rownum  |  user_id  | operation
1       |  1        | 'delete'
2       |  4        | 'add'
3       |  2        | 'create'
4       |  2        | 'delete'
```